# How to view HSQL in memory Database

Tags: java, jdbc

Hi I am using HSQL database,In that database i am using In Memory concept.I wrote the following code for creating database and tables.

```
Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                     "jdbc:hsqldb:mem", "SA", "");

String bookTableSQL = "create table MY_TABLE ("+
" TITLE varchar(256) not null primary key,"+
" AUTHOR varchar(256) not null"+
");";

Statement st = conn.createStatement();
st.execute(bookTableSQL);
System.out.println(st);
String sql = "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE " +
"VALUES ('arjun', 'Fatma')";

st.executeUpdate(sql);
System.out.println(st);
System.out.println("Inserted records into the table...");
```

In my project folder automatically created 4 files

1)mem.lck

2)mem.testDocument

3)mem.properties

4)mem.script

Q1)Among these files which one is my database?

Q2)How can i view created database and tables?

Any one have Idea please help me..

Comment: Among four files which one is my database?

Comment: This is not an in-memory database. The proper URL is `jdbc:hsqldb:mem:` (with the extra colon at the end). And then there will not be any files on disk for it. It will only be stored in memory.

Comment: can we see the database and table?